# How open URL in first time without log in on the Terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, browser, putty, raspberry-pi

I want to open a URL (for example`www.google.com`) from the terminal (SSH with PuTTY) on Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi.

I must first log into Kerio control webpage (`https://168.19...../`) then access the internet. I did enable `X11 forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` .

When I use the command `x-www-browser,epiphany`, I get this error:

> Unable to init server Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display

I can’t install any packages.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you will need to install Xming on your Windows machine, then change exactly **one** configuration in your Putty.

This is described very well [on this Web page](https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY), just follow those instructions.